# Dynamic fscanf into an array

Tags: c, file, input, scanf

I am trying to place some text into a structure part of my array is a array which takes part of the text.

For example my structure is:

```
struct animal
{
    char animal_Type[11];
    int age;
    int numberOfLegs;
    int walksPerDay;
    char favoriteFood[];
};
```

I will then have input such as:

```
dog,2,4,2,biscuits,wet
cat,5,4,0,biscuits,wet,dry,whiskers
bird,1,2,0,birdseed,biscuits,bread,oats,worms,insects,crackers
```

I have a working solution that places all the values up to walks per day into the structure, however I want to be able to place the food items into Favorite food. I have a dynamic array for this, but i'm not sure how to read remaining text into the favoriteFood array.

The code used is:

```
fp = open("animals.txt","r");
struct animal *animal = malloc(sizeof(sturct animal)*3);
int i = 0;
if(fp != NULL) {
     while(i < 3) {
fscanf(fp,"%s %d %d %d %s",
     animal[i].animal_Type,
     animal[i].age,
     animal[i].numberOfLegs,
     animal[i].walksPerDay,
     animal[i].favoriteFood); // need to be able to enter the string of food into here
i++
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: is the `favouriteFood` meant to contain "wet,dry,whiskers" or is it meant to be an array containing "wet", "dry", "whiskers"?

Comment: Ah, my appologies, should have made that clear. wet,dry,whiskers would all be seperate text in the array, so "wet","dry","whiskers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, your `struct` doesn't match what you've said in the comments.

```
char favoriteFood[];
```

The above is an array of `char`, so couldn't possibly hold a list of favourite foods except if it were one string. And since the size of the array is unspecified, you'd not be able to fill it like you have been either. Instead what you actually want is

```
char **favoriteFood;
unsigned int favoriteFoodSize;
```

That will let you create an expanding list of strings to fit whatever data you need to accommodate.

As for reading it in, the best way would be to read the entire line in using `fgets` and then use something like `strtok` to break the line up by your separator character. First define a very large string to hold the entire line and a `char *` to hold each field.

```
char buffer[1024];
char *token;
```

And then to the main loop would be something like this:

```
while(fgets(buffer,1024,fp)) {
    token=strtok(buffer,",");
    strcpy(beasts[i].animal_Type,token);

    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    beasts[i].age = atoi(token);

    /* etc... */
}
```

You'd need to check whether `token` is ever `NULL` to cope with the possibility of short lines and handle it accordingly. And also make sure that the string copied into `animal_Type` isn't longer than 10 characters...or alternative make it a `char *` so you can have any size of string.

For the `favoriteFood`, you'll need to use `realloc` to increase the size of it to accommodate each new food added and keep going through the string until you run out of tokens.

```
token=strtok(NULL,",");
if(token) {
    beasts[i].favoriteFood=malloc(sizeof(char *));
    beasts[i].favoriteFood[0]=strdup(token); // Need to index using 0 as favoriteFoodSize won't have a value yet
    beasts[i].favoriteFoodSize=1;

    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    while(token) {
        beasts[i].favoriteFood=realloc(beasts[i].favoriteFood,(beasts[i].favoriteFoodSize+1)*sizeof(char *));
        beasts[i].favoriteFood[beasts[i].favoriteFoodSize]=strdup(token);
        beasts[i].favoriteFoodSize++;

        token=strtok(NULL,",");
    }
}
```

The last food will have a `\n` in it as `fgets` keeps it in the buffer it reads, so you could use that to tell if you've finished processing all the foods (you will also need to remove it from the last food). Or if you don't have it, you know the line was longer and you'll need to read more in. But that seems unlikely based on your sample data.

And since you're doing lots of memory allocation, you should ensure that you check the values returned to make sure you've not run out of memory.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your reply. From what you have given me, it all seems to work perfectly up till the point in which it needs to add the favorite foods, at which point it just seems to crash. It also seems to only work with one line of text. I have put the code at: https://github.com/DcoltGaming/C - any chance you could tell me what I have done wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: Main thing you left out is you don't increment `i`. I can't see any reason why it would crash though. Perhaps one of your animal types is longer than 10 characters?

Comment: Ah...maybe it isn't actually crashing... I have put in the i++ however all I seem to have are memory addresses? https://imgur.com/a/4VojGpI

Comment: Memory addresses of the strings you've created?

Comment: Could be, but it dosen't seem to actually be creating the strings

Comment: That image isn't very clear, but it looks like you've stopped the code on the line where it creates the first string (that's what `strdup` does), so that'll be why it has the value it does cos it's not been set yet.

Comment: So it's not breaking it's saying there is a segmentation fault SIGSEGV

Comment: Ok, I think I know why I am getting the error but have no idea how to fix it. strdup is trying to pass a char from the toekn into favorite food size which is a int

Comment: I don't know what you're looking at, but nowhere in my answer or the code you've got on github is doing that - `strdup` returns a `char *` and `favoriteFoodSize` is being used as an index into the `favoriteFood` "array" being allocated

Comment: Doh! I can see what is wrong...updating the answer cos I've been stupid

Comment: Crucially it was using `favoriteFoodSize` before it was set to a value...so causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be pretty much there. The only thing i'm confused about is printing it. How would I know how many favoriteFoods are assigned to each animal?..Here is my attempt to print: https://imgur.com/a/I0ydg4J

Comment: Is it not obvious that the `favoriteFoodSize` is the number of foods each animal has?